# how to use set operations in julia language

Tags: julia

I want to use `set()` as in python in Julia. Is it possible to do so? If yes, please provide an example using the following python code

```
set(A) - set(B)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant functionality is explained in [the docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#set-like-collections).  While you can still use `-`, it's been deprecated:

```
julia> A = [1,2,3]; B = [2,3,4];

julia> Set(A) - Set(B)
WARNING: a::Set - b::Set is deprecated, use setdiff(a,b) instead.
 in - at deprecated.jl:26
Set{Int32}({1})

julia> setdiff(A, B)
1-element Array{Int32,1}:
 1

julia> setdiff(Set(A), Set(B))
Set{Int32}({1})
```

Note that we can use setlike ops on arrays directly, in which case they're order-preserving.

Comment: Julia's documentation link you provided isn't working anymore.
Correct link is here : https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Set-Like-Collections-1

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the filter command. This way you will get an array back.

```
julia> A = [1; 2; 3]; B = [2; 3; 4; 5];
julia> filter(x -> !(x in A), B)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
4
5
```